# VBA Listbox not updating to reflect new source list when called from itself

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

**Edit:**

Playing around further, it seems that  you *can't* assign a new array to a listbox via the .list=somelist approach when the assignment happens in response to a click on the listbox itself. Or rather, you can assign the list, but it simply won't visually populate the listbox...although Excel seems to think it's there.

The .additem or .removeitem methods do however result in a visual change when called from a listbox click, which means you have to build your new array up that way I guess. How tedious.

You *can* however feed a listbox an entirely new array using the .list=somelist approach via  a CommandButton-initiated action. But the user has to obviously click a button to do this. Which in my case below defeats the purpose.

**Edit Over.**

I'm designing a UserForm to help filter PivotTables. It's a cross between the existing Pivot Filter functionality and a Slicer. Here's what you see if you double-click on a PivotField header:

[image]

Note the Search field at the top, and the three buttons immediately below that search field. If you type something into that field, then instead of displaying everything that's currently filtered, you instead get a list of any matches, and you can then apply those search results to the underlying PivotTable via those three CommandButtons. The first cb simply filters the PivotTable to reflect the search, and the other two let you add or remove any search result from an existing filter.

I want to do away with those three command buttons, and instead (in the event that a search is performed) simply list those three options at the top of the ListBox above any search results returned. Clicking on those three options will then trigger the exact same code as currently triggered by the Command Button.

Here's how that looks currently if I actually type something in that Search box (Note I haven't yet removed the three command buttons this does away with from that Search frame):

[image]

I've added a simple bit of code to the lbResults_Change() event handler that checks if a user clicks any of those first three options. All that code does is trigger the *exact same* routines as would be triggered if they'd simply clicked on the actual command buttons themselves:

```
For i = 0 To 4
    If Me.lbResults.Selected(i) Then Exit For
Next i
Select Case i
    Case 0: cmdApplySearch_Click
    Case 1: cmdAddToFilter_Click
    Case 2: cmdSubtractFromFilter_Click
    Case 3: Me.lbResults.Selected(3) = False
End Select
```

**Here' the problem:** The listbox gets updated just fine if I click on those command buttons, as you can see from the below. The Pivot has been filtered accordingly, and those contextual search options have been removed from the top of the listbox (and the search field cleared):

[image]

But the listbox does NOT get updated if the *exact same routine* is triggered from a click on one of those top three options in listbox itself:

[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, it still shows those three options at the top, even though they are NOT in the array that I assigned to the listbox, as evidenced by the screenshot below:

[image]

But as you could see from the earlier screenshot, it shows 7 items in the ListBox instead of the three there actually are. But there are indeed just three items that should be showing in that list box:

? .ListCount
3 
? .List(0)
263213: ICT Systems Test Engineer
? .List(1)
263299: ICT Support and Test Engineers nec
? .List(2)
839313: Product Tester

Basically, as soon as I try to update what's in the listbox via a click on the listbox itself, I can't update it.

It doesn't seem to matter if I set focus to something other than the listbox before the filtering code executes, and I've even tried completely clearing the Listbox with .clear. It just doesn't clear, until I manually click on one of those command buttons again.

Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: I thought this would make an interesting blogpost, so added some more commentary as well as a simple sample file and posted it at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/11/04/listbox-bulk-refresh-wont-redraw-if-called-by-listbox-click/ if anyone's interested.

If any new info turns up at that blogpost, I'll be sure to update this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, what an idiot I am for overlooking the painfully obvious solution. The ListBox list happily redraws in response to any event *other* than the ListBox_Click event, right? So all I needed to do was to use the ListBox_**Click** event to determine what got clicked (as I currently do), and then use the ListBox_**MouseUp** event to trigger the actual updating of the ListBox list. Works a treat.

Hopefully this post will save someone else two days of pain in the future. Probably me.